# How do I connect multiple machines to an energy bridge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've got an energy bridge converting my EU power to MJ and when I put a machine that runs on MJ directly next to the BC producer, it works. I've tried to connect 3 of these types of machines to the BC producer using conductive stone pipes but the machines do not charge.

I'm sure the conductive pipes are supposed to transmit MJ energy, so what have I missed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a normal buildcraft power distribution setup requires that wooden conductive pipes be used to extract energy from a source, stone or golden (so much better that they should be used whenever possible) conductive pipes can then be used to connect from the wooden conductive pipes to wherever the energy needs to go.

Comment: or redstone conduits from factorisation

Comment: @ratchetfreak Redstone Energy Conduits are from Thermal Expansion. And, once you are able to make them (rather later game than BuildCraft conductive pipes) are much more effective. Just don't forget to change the input to orange (blue is output) with an appropriate wrench.